# pandas - how to swap first two elements in a multi-value column

Tags: pandas

I have below data

> SFDC,CMN,CMID,SID,MID,C_PG,ACT
> DCA,customer1,company1,SID1,cherie,cherie,"view_page_modulepicker,explore_more_connect
> with people"
> DCA,customer2,company2,SID2,cherie,cherie,"view_manage_opportunities,view_page_modulepicker,back_to_opp,view_page_modulepicker"
> DCA,customer1,company1,SID1,cherie,cherie,"view_manage_opportunities,view_page_modulepicker,explore_more_connect
> with people"
> DCA,customer1,company1,SID1,cherie,cherie,"view_page_modulepicker"
> DCA,customer1,company1,SID1,cherie,cherie,"view_manage_opportunities"
> DCA,customer4,company1,SID4,cherie,cherie,"view_manage_opportunities,view_page_actionSource"
> DCA,customer4,company1,SID4,cherie,cherie,"view_manage_opportunities,view_page_homePage"
> DCA,customer4,company1,SID4,cherie,cherie,"view_manage_opportunities,view_page_capabilities"
> ...... ......

Now i want to find the rows that first element in ACT column is 'view_manage_opportunities', and second element in ACT column is 'view_page(.*)'

then swap these two elements . so the expected output is

> SFDC,CMN,CMID,SID,MID,C_PG,ACT
> DCA,customer1,company1,SID1,cherie,cherie,"view_page_modulepicker,explore_more_connect
> with people"
> DCA,customer2,company2,SID2,cherie,cherie,"view_page_modulepicker,view_manage_opportunities,back_to_opp,view_page_modulepicker"
> DCA,customer1,company1,SID1,cherie,cherie,"view_page_modulepicker,view_manage_opportunities,explore_more_connect
> with people"
> DCA,customer1,company1,SID1,cherie,cherie,"view_page_modulepicker"
> DCA,customer1,company1,SID1,cherie,cherie,"view_manage_opportunities"
> DCA,customer4,company1,SID4,cherie,cherie,"view_page_actionSource,view_manage_opportunities"
> DCA,customer4,company1,SID4,cherie,cherie,"view_page_homePage,view_manage_opportunities"
> DCA,customer4,company1,SID4,cherie,cherie,"view_page_capabilities,view_manage_opportunities"
> ...... ......

can any expert help on this requirement with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["ACT"] = df["ACT"].str.replace(r'(view_manage_opportunities),(view_page[^,]*)', r'\2,\1')
```

Check the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/NiZzB7/2).